# Is there a DOM event that fires when an HTML select element is opened in iOS?

Tags: jquery, ios, html-select

I'm looking to fire off some jQuery as soon as a select menu is opened on an iOS device (you know, when the beautiful "drum" slides up from the bottom of the screen).

I've scoured the site but can't find anything on this. If anyone knows of said event, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`.focus`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/). I set up [a basic fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8sSUm/) and it works on my iPhone 4S with iOS 6.